# When passing pointers to a class, who should manage the resources?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a gui api for games. I have for example a font for each widget in the form of a Font* . Right now I have it so that I do not ever manage the memory of these (for obvious reasons) because I think the user can use smart pointers if they want this memory managed. The con to this is that it is not very idiot proof. If a user set the font like this:

```
obj.setFont(new Font(""));
```

This would immediately cause a memory leak because no one ever frees it. The only way would be to delete getFont();

Would it be instead better for me to manage these?

Thanks

Comment: Get arguments per const-reference where possible, use smart-pointers elsewhere, define what instance owns what other instances (i.e. what defines the life-time of an object) carefully.

Comment: You can't be responsible for someone typing this: `obj.setFont(new Font(""));` any more than you can be responsible for someone typing `new Font("");` on a line by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the responsibility of the caller to manage the memory of objects that are within the caller's scope.

That being said, in this case, you should really use smart pointers because they will deallocate themselves when they are no longer of use.

Comment: I do not want to use smart pointers because I want my library to be c++ 03 complaint

Comment: @Milo How is your library not C++03 compliant if you use smart pointers?

Comment: +1 @Milo: Boost is not an option I guess ? @Jacob Relkin: Smart pointers do not necessarily deallocate the pointee: You can create a smart pointer to a stack-allocated instance with a *null deleter* and use it transparently within the function.

Comment: @Milo - Oh I see, you want to only rely on the standard libs and whatever you write, not on external dependencies.

Comment: I disagree.  It would run contrary to almost all UI libraries out there and thus would be rather counterintuitive.  Most UI libraries provide for exactly the kind of use the OP is describing.  Who should manage a resource is not necessarily, in fact not usually, answered by who created it.  Who should manage it is who is considered to *own* it.  In this case, the object who's font it IS seems quite appropriate.

Comment: @ereOn - that's only true of SOME smart pointers, in fact only one I can think of off the top of my head: shared_ptr.  This particular smart pointer would not be appropriate here.  If you're going to use smart pointers then you should use the right ones.  Ownership transference is better indicated by std::unique_ptr or std::auto_ptr if you lack the former.

Answer (score 3):

It's your decision if your library should take ownership of the resource, but whatever you choose, make it clear through the interface (and not only through comments or documentation).

- In C++03, a good way to make it explicit that you are actually taking ownership is to receive the parameter as a `std::auto_ptr` : the client will have no doubt that he's transferring ownership
- On the opposite, receiving a parameter through const reference should make it clear that you have no intention to ever delete the data (you can't possibly know if it has actually been new'ed in the first place).

Anyway, going for smart pointers would probably help with these questions.

Comment: I would have gone with this answer except that smart pointers or references are not necessarily necessary.  If you are consistent in your rules of ownership so that users need only learn a couple things to be able to know what's what then smart pointers can be overkill and possibly inappropriate depending on what set you have (shared_ptr for instance is not a good choice for ownership transference).

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with transferred ownership.

But: You can rewrite your interface to

```
void obj.setFont( SmartPtr<Font> font );
```

because then you are forcing the user to use a smart pointer.